# Check adherence of question about project organization to community guidelines

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

My question was closed, after initial criticism that it was too broad. I reacted to that by throwing away the second part of the question and trying to narrow it down.

**Q:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430234/modern-c-project-layout

I saw other questions that were similar. I understand that SO isn't a poll, but I think the question I asked, especially after editing, is viable.

Could you please reevaluate the question and give me future hints for question of the same kind, i.e. what are the common industrial/acadamical techniques to address problem X?

Comment: That question *still* seems very opinion based, as most "best style" questions are. As Servy notes though, it is already in the reopen queue, no need to ask on Meta.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes, I know, but that's inherent in 'best style' questions. I still want to gain knowledge in that area. ...I'll guess I'll wait for the results of the reopen queue.

Comment: Saying that people should provide facts, and not opinions, doesn't make a question any less opinion based.  If I say, "What is everyone's favorite color, oh, and btw you should only post facts, not your own opinions" then it's still an opinion based question.  You stating at the end that people shouldn't post opinions does nothing to change that.

Comment: I didn't say that. Here the sentence you are refering to`In order to keep the question as objective as possible, could provide empirical data from professional experience in companies rather than focussing only on personal preferences.`.

Answer (score 2):

The question will have already entered the reopen queue when you edited it.  There it will be evaluated to see if it should be reopened.